# A well-known lemma about curvilinear circles!

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-transformation

> Let $AB$ be a chord of a circle $\Gamma$. Let $\omega$ be a circle tangent to chord $AB$ at $K$ and internally tangent to $\omega$ at $T$. Then ray $TK$ passes through the midpoint $M$ of the arc $AB$ not containing $T$.

** This question might be asked before. If them don't down vote. Just close it marking duplicate and send me the link of the question. I search out but failed to find **.[image]

I tried my best by doing angle chasing but failed.I think radical axis will not work as well. If anyone have any pure geometry answer please post. I think inversion will work. But i know inversion a little. But I guess Inversion around $M$ will work. Please help me.

Comment: An inversion around M with radius AM works too. This would swap the line AB and big circumcircle, and thus it must preserve the small circle by preservation of tangents. Then we're done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

Homothety in $T$ which takes smaller circle to bigger will do. It takes $K$ to $M$ and line $AB$ to parallel line through $M$ since $K$ is on $AB$. Thus this new line is also tangent to bigger circle, since $AB$ is tangent to smaller. Now it should not be difficult to see that $AMB$ is isosceles (remember tangent-chord property).